# Giving the content of ca.pem file as hard coded string in delphi for SSL connection

Tags: mysql, delphi, ssl, x509certificate, mydac

I have a MySQL server and I have the client certificate and keys for SSL connection to the MYSQL server.
In delphi that uses MyDAC for connecting to mysql, I can use:

```
MySQL1Connection.SSLOptions.CACert := 'file location'
MySQL1Connection.SSLOptions.Cert := 'file location'
MySQL1Connection.SSLOptions.Key := 'file location'
MySQL1Connection.SSLOptions.ChipherList := 'All';
MySQL1Connection.Options.Protocol := mpSSL;
```

But the problem in the above application is that, I have to supply the files to the client. 
Now, I want to hardcode the content of the file in the .exe, such that I will not have to deliver the files to the client.

Do you know any cleaver way to do this?

Comment: Embed it as a resource in the EXE. then extract it via TResourceStream to a temp folder. when done, delete it.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I got another way of doing it. There is a storage component in the securebridge component list. Using that component will solve the problem.

Comment: Please post that as an answer to your own question. explain which component did you use and how, so it could be useful to others.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem by using the TScFileStorage component of secure bridge components (https://www.devart.com/sbridge/components.html)

The steps are available in the the section 3. of this link: https://www.devart.com/mydac/docs/?secureconnections.htm